# debian won't boot with full hd monitor

Tags: debian, boot, gnome

There is a server, debian 11.5 is installed, GNOME was selected as the desktop environment during installation.

During the installation of the OS, a monitor of 1280x1024 was used and now the system simply does not start (grub is loaded, debian starts, debian's codes fly by quickly with the inscription ok and that's it, a black screen, the system does not respond, no services have starte) if a monitor of 1920x1080 is installed, but if you install the monitor of 1280x1024 again and restart the computer (ctrl+alt+del), then the system turns on as expected

hardware:

- motherboard: X12DAi-N6
- cpu: 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4314 CPU @2.40GHz

Comment: nothing in the Linux boot process even cares about an external monitor. What does "the system simply does not start" mean, **exactly**? Is this maybe a hardware issue?

Comment: @MarcusMüller grub is loaded, debian starts, debian's codes fly by quickly with the inscription ok and that's it, a black screen, the system does not respond, no services have started.

I connect a square monitor, restart the computer and everything works

Comment: Thanks. I've added that info to your question. You say "no services are started", so I guess that means network doesn't come up, either?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, you understood correctly, the network also did not rise, or rather it is strange there, another ip address was received via dhcp (I saw it through arp-scan), and not the one that was received before, but at the same time other network services, such as ssh, web server, docker, etc. did not work. I don't know if there was no dhcp, it would have gone up or not.

Comment: I didn't have time to see while I was near the server whether the console was working via `alt+right`, but it didn't seem to work before (the problem appeared a week ago, but was not critical, and now it has become critical).  I also tried using xrandr to add `1920 1080 60`, because the `xrandr` output showed only one mode - `1280 x 1024`, but it didn't help

Comment: what is `"alt-right"` supposed to do? if you want to switch virtual terminals, you use `ctrl-alt-Fn` where `n` is 1 to 7 (or more) usually on Debian

Comment: @JaromandaX `alt-right` is an analogue of `ctrl-alt-Fn`, I tried both options, for some reason I just have switching through `ctrl-alt-Fn` works every other time, and through `alt-right` - always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to solving this problem.

The problem was not in the drivers, monitor, etc., but in the fact that by default debian 11 Gnome DE uses *wayland*, which for some reason does not want to work with 16x9. Why it doesn't work, I already didn't figure it out and replaced *wayland* with *X11*.

Solution:

Edit the file `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`
***(in some distributions, for example, on my computer with ubuntu22, not `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` is used, but `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, so be careful)***

There will be a commented out line: `#WaylandEnable=false`.
You need to uncomment it, and then add this line: `DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop`

The **daemon** section will be something like this:

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop
```

After reboot, both the square and 16x9 monitors work and auto detect the resolution.